# PHP REST API - PUT Displaying 404

Tags: php, rest

I am trying to make a simple web service, that updates a field when a page is hit. I have tried to simply the code for the purposes of stack overflow. When I try to go to the page but it's bringing a 404.

Firstly here is my web service code (I'm using SLIM) (I've missed out the database connection stuff):

```
$app->put('/offer/:id', 'updateOffer');    
function updateOffer($id) {
        global $app;
        $req = $app->request();
        $increment = $req->params('increment');
        $sql = "UPDATE offers SET claims=:increment WHERE id=:id";
        try {
            $dbCon = getConnection();
            $stmt = $dbCon->prepare($sql);  
            $stmt->bindParam("increment", $increment);
            $stmt->bindParam("id", $id);
            $status->status = $stmt->execute();
            $dbCon = null;
            echo json_encode($status); 
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
        }
    }
```

and on the page I want to visit the code is as follows:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/api/offer/'.$id1;
$fields = array(
                        'id' => urlencode($id),
                        'increment' => urlencode($increment)

                );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

I just can't get my head around where I am going wrong. I can get it to work with a FORM (so I know the web service works)

Comment: Your HTTP server may not support the `PUT` verb by default. Consult the documentation. Also, your title says PUT, but your code says POST.

Comment: This really doesn't affect anything because I'm sure the count ends up being evaluated by a boolean but `CURLOPT_POST, count($fields)` isn't right.  CURLOPT_POST is supposed to be true or false, not an integer.  However, if you're doing a PUT, you should be using `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT'` not post.

Comment: The curl request goes to 'localhost/api/offer/'.  The function updateOffer() included in the first code excerpt has nothing to do with it. The 404 code is not related to database update. Please post the right code.

Comment: Sorry, I just uodated the PHP to include that